# Create faces database from images with openCV?

Tags: database, opencv

I'm writing a program that detect faces from images; and recognize a face from an input image, using OpenCV library. I was done with detection part, but in recognization part, I don't know how to create faces database from detected faces. I read several samples about face recog using Eigenfaces, and it requires at least 2 faces per person from an available database - that I do not have.

My question is how to create the database, it's not just crop each face and store in a named folder, because maybe there're same faces in different images. Is there a way to compare those faces and group them in one folder?

Many thanks, and sorry for my poor English (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this link, there are some face datasets that you could use, it also explains how-to Face recognition

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already read that link, those face datasets cannot help me because I want to train and find face from my own database. The problem is, if I just crop each face and store them to named folder like: person1, person2,... => each person has only one face in database => cannot train. My images have same faces in different images, so my question is Is there anyway to group those same faces to only one person database?

Comment: You would have to give each person an id. Then by recognising the face it can classify it into the same id.